# Override default Browser in unity-mail

Tags: unity

Default Bowser is Firefox. This should stay like this. I want to click on unity-mail button and chrome should open instead of Firefox. Is this possible. Is there a switch in .config/unity-mail.conf?. I can't find any documentation.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: 
https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-mail/+question/212243

Add this to your config or simply edit in the config pane (right mouse click on icon -> Change Account details) and add your values for every task (Home, Compose, Inbox & Sent).

```
[URLs]
Home = Exec:google-chrome https://mail.google.com/mail/
Compose = Exec:google-chrome https://mail.google.com/mail/#compose
Inbox = Exec:google-chrome https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox
Sent = Exec:google-chrome https://mail.google.com/mail/#sent
```

Comment: In the long run Ubuntu should provide a possibility to set a Browser as a Mail client in System Setting -> Details -> Default Application

Comment: if this is the correct answer you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your default browser:

change **system-settings -> details -> default applications -> web** to chrome.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I dont want. My gmail account should be binded to chrome as I have written in the question. Firefox should still be default for "web".

Comment: I got it buddy.sorry.